# WebView muy lento en Android

Tags: java, android, webview, webview-android

En mi aplicación de Android estoy usando un `WebView`, pero este va muy lento para algunos contenidos por lo que deja de ser útil. He probado a actualizar el `WebView` del dispositivo de pruebas pero ello no ha aportado nada. También he probado las siguientes líneas y ninguna ha servido:

En `AndroidManifest`:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

En `MainActivity`:

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma de optimizar el uso de `WebView` ya que las anteriores no me han servido.

Comment: que estás tratando de cargar en el webView?

Comment: Una página web en la que se van mostrando contenidos de redes sociales a modo de presentación. Aunuqe con el resto también va un poco lento, esta web no se llega a cargar.

Comment: Aporta mas datos a tu pregunta, al menos puedes mostrar la url que deseas cargar? Porque no agregas el código de tu implementacion? , recuerda que el webview en android es un browser con caracteristicas limitadas. Veo que has agregado varias preguntas similares pero no aportas demasiada información... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84406/abrir-web-pesada-en-app